# is my epsilon-delta proof correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I am a complete beginner with limits and I self study, so I don't have anyone to confirm my answers. I had a simple limit to prove with the precise definition, its a linear equation and I did lots of these already but I want to be sure because I don't feel like I am ready to continue. Here is what I did:

$$ \lim_{x \to -3}(7x-9)=-30 $$
$$ |7x-9+30|< \epsilon $$
$$ 7|x+3|< \epsilon $$
$$ |x+3| < \frac{\epsilon}{7} $$
$$ \bbox[1px, border: 1px solid black]
{
\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{7}
}
$$

---

and with the delta I can move on to the formal proof:

$$ 0<|x+3|<\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{7} $$
$$ 0<7|x+3|<7\cdot \frac{\epsilon}{7} $$
$$ 0<|7x+21|<\epsilon $$
$$ 0<|7x-9+30|<\epsilon \ \ \blacksquare $$

---

Is this correct?

Comment: Did you mean $x+3$ in 3rd and 4th line?

Comment: It's quite confusing and not really clear, but if I see just the last part, it ok (but not really well made).

Comment: $|7x-9+30|=|7x+21|=7|x+3|$ Are you sure?

Comment: Hume2 is right, I accidentally wrote x-3 instead of x+3, thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For a rigorous proof :**

We have that $$|(7x-9)+30|=7|x-3|.$$

Let $\varepsilon >0$. Set $\delta =\frac{\varepsilon }{7}$. If $|x-3|\leq \delta $, then $$|(7x-9)+30|=7|x-3|\leq 7\cdot \delta =7\cdot \frac{\varepsilon }{7}=\varepsilon .$$
Since $\varepsilon >0$ is unspecified, the claim follow.

Comment: How can I know whats delta? I think what I did on the first part was good and as I get more experience I will be able to find delta more intuitively. Is that the case for you?

Comment: You find the $\delta $ on your draft.

Comment: I think you should set $\delta = min(1, \frac{\epsilon}{7})$

Answer (score 1):

It's good. I particularly like the way you distinguish between the proof and the calculation. On that point, when proving, you can go a step further and omit the calculation. Simply start by assuming $\varepsilon > 0$ and $0 < |x + 3| < \frac{\varepsilon}{7}$. Then, your steps show that $|7x - 9 + 30| < \varepsilon$, proving $\lim_{x \to -3} (7x - 9) = -30$.

Comment: thank you. As a beginner, I find it hard to omit the calculations on the first part. I hope I will get a better understanding of it as time goes on.